# NSXMLParser - the request timed out

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

I have been intermittently receiving a "The request timed out" message via the NSXMLParser parseError method. (NSError)

It doesn't happen in the simulator only on the actual device. (i4)

On the device it usualy happens when the app being launched the first time.

Once I have the first parse done (after one or two app restart) every other web service call will work just fine.

I can then restart the app as many times as I want it won't show the error anymore.

I don't see how this is a timeout error as the app won't hang up. The error pops up instantly.

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the code for the first parse?

Answer (score 0):

I could never figure out this error. It looks like this message appears only when the connection is very slow.